# I need explanation for reaction rate

Tags: kinetics

That's a sample reaction:
$$2N_2+3O_2->2N_2O_3\ \ \ r=k_1[N_2]^2[O_2]^3$$
Why can't I write this as
$$N_2+\frac{3}{2}O_2->N_2O_3\ \ \ r=k_2[N_2][O_2]^{\frac{3}{2}}$$
Don't bother the elements. Assume it's elementary not mechanism.

Comment: First kinetic eq. is incorrect, second probably too.

Comment: Furthermore, $N_2$ and $O_2$ have the greatest difficulty to make any reaction at all. And if they react, they will produce $NO$ or $NO_2$, and never $N_2O_3$.

Comment: The rate law doesn't change when multiply equation of the  reaction

Comment: I'd rather make a sample out of a reaction that actually _can_ occur.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/38167/do-coefficients-matter-in-rate-law/38169#38169

Answer (score 3):

A rate law is never deduced from a theoretical equation. NEVER. It is always obtained form experimental measurements. It may happen that the order of the reaction is equal to the stoichiometric coefficient.

Comment: This is a bit over the top. I agree that a reaction which such a high reaction order is unlikely to be an elementary reaction which book problems often assume.