# Writing rate of disappearance and rate of appearance using rate law

Tags: physical-chemistry, kinetics, rate-equation

I have studied that rate of disappearance and rate of appearance is the change in concentration of reactants and products (respectively) with respect to time.  Thus,

$$\text{ROD} = -\frac{\Delta c_R}{\Delta T}$$

and

$$\text{ROA} = \frac{\Delta c_P}{\Delta T}$$

and

$$\text{rate of reaction} = %
%
\frac{\text{ROD}} {\text{stoichiometric coefficient}} %
%
= \frac{\text{ROA}} {\text{stoichiometric coefficient} }$$

Then writing rate of reaction using ***rate law*** was taught.

And according to rate law rate of reaction can be expressed as:

$$\text{rate of reaction} = k[\ce{A}]^x[\ce{B}]^y$$

here $x + y = \text{overall order of reaction}$, with $\ce{A}$ and $\ce{B}$, the reactants.

Here is my confusion:  Now they wrote rate of disappearance and appearance using rate law. How using rate law they wrote expression for ROA and ROD.

For a reaction:  $\ce{aA -> bB}$ (elementary reaction), it was stated that:
$$\text{ROD}_\text{A} = k_d [\ce{A}]^a$$

So how ?

Using rate law we can write rate of reaction.. (OK) but how can we write ROA and ROD ??!!

Hope you understood what I meant to say.

Comment: How did you come to the last equation?

Comment: @PoutnikCan we relate rate law with ROD of  reactant A as this formula : ***Rate of reaction*** = $-\frac{1}{Stoichiometric\space Coefficient\space  of \space reactant A}\cdot\frac{\Delta[A]}{\Delta{t}} = k[A]^x[B]^y$

Comment: @Poutnik I have made amendment to the reaction. Sorry for caused ambiguity. Now can you please explain how we can write ROD and ROA using RATE LAW ?

Comment: IF ROD(A)=ROR . SC and if ROR= k . [A]^x . [B]^y then .......

Comment: If there is text in the equation, set this as text (cf. the revision). A `$ROD = x $` means $R \cdot O \cdot D$ (a multiplication) yielding $x$ as a product; using `$\text{ROD}$ = x$` however states $\text{ROD} = x$, i.e. the variable ROD equates to $x$.  And for the use of \mhchem syntax: have a look [here](https://mhchem.github.io/MathJax-mhchem/). Take moment to familiarize with this. You are encouraged to use it in the body of questions, answers, and comments. Because it is something special not all web browsers understand well, *do not* use it in the title of questions or answers.

Comment: @Buttonwood What is this ? "Stoichiometric space Coefficient" ? Why have you inserted "space" word at some points ? I think that's a mistake in your edit

Comment: @VishalAnand Look at the revision history.  Because you did enter text in mathmode without clear pattern like `$\text{my variable} = 12$`, you used `\space` to separate the words.  In equations, I don't use `\space` commands; this is why the previous edit showed them *as remains* of your approach.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do coefficients matter in rate law?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/38167/do-coefficients-matter-in-rate-law)

Answer (score 1):

You overthink it.
It is just matter of eventual multiplication or division with respective stoichiometric coefficients.

If there is an elementary reaction

$$\ce{a A -> b B}$$

then for respective reaction, appearance and disappearance rates:

$$\begin{align}
R_\mathrm{r} &= k_\mathrm{r}[A]^a\\
R_\mathrm{a,B} = \frac {\mathrm{d[B]}}{\mathrm{d[t]}}=bR_\mathrm{r} &= bk_\mathrm{r}[A]^a = k_\mathrm{a,B}[A]^a\\
R_\mathrm{d,A} = -\frac {\mathrm{d[A]}}{\mathrm{d[t]}} = aR_\mathrm{r} &= ak_\mathrm{r}[A]^a = k_\mathrm{d,A}[A]^a
\end{align}$$

.. and backwards:

$$\begin{align}
R_\mathrm{r} = \frac{R_\mathrm{a,B} }{ b} &= \frac 1b  \frac {\mathrm{d[B]}}{ \mathrm{d[t]}}\\
R_\mathrm{r} = \frac{R_\mathrm{d,A} }{ a} &= -\frac 1a \frac {\mathrm{d[A]}}{\mathrm{d[t]}}
\end{align}$$

Comment: thanks .According to your solution can  we conclude the following expression :$-\frac 1a \frac {\mathrm{d[A]}}{\mathrm{d[t]}}= k_\mathrm{r}[A]^a$

Comment: @AdnanAL-Amleh If X=Y and X=Z then obviously Y=Z. :-)

Comment: Thanks . Can we teach the following expression for 11th grade . Is it correct?: $\text{average}R_\mathrm{r} = \frac{\text{average}R_\mathrm{d,A} }{ a} = -\frac 1a \frac {\mathrm{\Delta[A]}}{\mathrm{\Delta[t]}}= k_\mathrm{r}[A]^a$

Comment: @AdnanAL-Amleh Involving deltas and averages, you have to come with average for $\ce{[A]}^a$ too. If the delta is about 10% and a=3, it makes about 30% difference. It is a task for integration.

Comment: thanks  .
Is it useful to teach the following two expressions separately without reconciliation or connection  between them ,as the first expression about instantaneous rate and rate law but the second about average rate
1)$R_\mathrm{r} = -\frac 1a \frac {\mathrm{d[A]}}{\mathrm{d[t]}}= \frac 1b  \frac {\mathrm{d[B]}}{ \mathrm{d[t]}}= k_\mathrm{r}[A]^a $\
2)$R_\mathrm{r} = -\frac 1a \frac {\mathrm{\Delta{[A]}}}{\mathrm{\Delta{t}}}= \frac 1b  \frac {\Delta\mathrm{[B]}}{\Delta\mathrm{t}}$